# Import resource in spring bean

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, import

I want to import xml resource file in spring bean so how can i do it?i have already tried below code but its not working.

```
<beans profile="en_US">
<import resource="Test.xml" />
</beans>
```

Comment: The question is poorly described. Could you please describe your question in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use classpath in your import tag, like this:

```
<beans profile="en_US">
    <import resource="classpath:Test.xml" />
</beans>
```

Assuming that `Test.xml` is located in your classpath.